# CSS - Floats mis-aligning on window width change

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

```
#imgseasonal{
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}
.colseasonalfirst{
    width:215px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0px;
    text-align:center;
}
.colseasonal{
    text-align:center;
    width:215px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

Screenshot one:https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjtXp.jpg
Screenshot two:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipt7v.jpg

Im having a difficult time having these columns stay in an aligned row on certain window sizes. The columns dont go all the way to the left on the second row. When I shrink them more, the problem gets worse. Am I missing a key element of css to help remedy this alignment issue?

Comment: What you want to happen can only happen if the columns all have identical heights. What actually happens is that the first column that doesn't fit in the available width will move down to clear the float. And after it has moved down, it won't move back up.

Comment: I had a feeling it was going to be something simple. But not as simple as that! Thank you so much :) It corrected the alignment on all window width sizes.